# getting correct index of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have to compare np.arrays pairwise and I need the index back.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
Vals = np.array([[1.0, 1.0], [2., 2.], [1., 2.], [2., 1.], [3., 3.], [3., 3.]])
for Val in itertools.combinations(Vals,2):
    X1 = Val[0][0]
    X2 = Val[1][0]
    Y1 = Val[0][1]
    Y2 = Val[1][1]
    Index1 = np.where( (Vals == Val[0]).all(axis=1))[0][0]
    Index2 = np.where( (Vals == Val[1]).all(axis=1))[0][0]
    
    print(X1,Y1,Index1)
    print(X2,Y2,Index2)
```

This runs fine until two or more tuple with the same values are in Vals (as in the example).
np.where gives back the first occurence of this tuple in the array and so I get the wrong index back.
How can I get the correct index?

Comment: Suggest you to add the expected output which will help not just address problem in your code but also help others on SO to suggest new approaches

Comment: An please tell us why the first occurrence given by where is not correct because it's the normal behaviour of the function.

Comment: The arrays are related to other data. If you run the code you will see, that the array [3.,3.] has always the index 4, but there are two arrays with the same values and I need two know the correct index. As I wrote, the code runs fine if every array is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(Vals)), 2):
    print(Vals[i], i, "|", Vals[j], j)
```

```
[1. 1.] 0 | [2. 2.] 1
[1. 1.] 0 | [1. 2.] 2
[1. 1.] 0 | [2. 1.] 3
[1. 1.] 0 | [3. 3.] 4
[1. 1.] 0 | [3. 3.] 5
[2. 2.] 1 | [1. 2.] 2
[2. 2.] 1 | [2. 1.] 3
[2. 2.] 1 | [3. 3.] 4
[2. 2.] 1 | [3. 3.] 5
[1. 2.] 2 | [2. 1.] 3
[1. 2.] 2 | [3. 3.] 4
[1. 2.] 2 | [3. 3.] 5
[2. 1.] 3 | [3. 3.] 4
[2. 1.] 3 | [3. 3.] 5
[3. 3.] 4 | [3. 3.] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using zip to iterate over each array in tandem

Comment: How can I do this and avoid, that an array is compared with itself?